# OpenCV error when Docker container is run on GKE

Tags: c++, node.js, opencv, docker

I get the following error when running OpenCV via nodejs in a Docker container on GKE, but don't experience the issue when running the same container on my Mac.

Is this some sort of memory issue? Only the node process crashes.

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Invalid cascade pointer) in cvRunHaarClassifierCascadeSum, file /tmp/opencv-2.4.11/modules/objdetect/src/haar.cpp, line 838
>   OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Invalid cascade pointer) in cvRunHaarClassifierCascadeSum, file /tmp/opencv-2.4.11/modules/objdetect/src/haar.cpp, line 838
>   OpenCV Error: Null pointer (Hidden cascade has not been created.
>   Use cvSetImagesForHaarClassifierCascade) in cvRunHaarClassifierCascadeSum, file /tmp/opencv-2.4.11/modules/objdetect/src/haar.cpp, line 843
>   OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Invalid cascade pointer) in cvRunHaarClassifierCascadeSum, file /tmp/opencv-2.4.11/modules/objdetect/src/haar.cpp, line 838
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tbb::captured_exception'
>     what():  /tmp/opencv-2.4.11/modules/objdetect/src/haar.cpp:838: error: (-5) Invalid cascade pointer in function cvRunHaarClassifierCascadeSum

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the NodeJS library Faced. I used the Node OpenCV library instead.